# Null pointer exception in One To Many Mapping example

Tags: java, hibernate

Employee class :

public class Employee {

```
private int EMPLOYEE_ID;

private int FACULTY_NO;

private int ENROLMENT_NO;

private String FIRSTNAME;

private String LASTNAME;

private Date BIRTH_DATE;

private String CELLPHONE;

private Department DEP;

//getters and setters
```

}

Department class :

public class Department {

```
private Long DEPARTMENT_ID;

private String DEPARTMENT_NAME;

private String DEPARTMENT_LOCATION;

private String DEPARTMENT_RANK;

Set<Employee> EMPLOYEE_LIST;

    // getters and setters
```

}

IMPl class :

public class OneToManyImpl {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Department department = new Department();

    department.setDEPARTMENT_NAME("Mechanical Dept.");

    department.setDEPARTMENT_RANK("A class");

    department.setDEPARTMENT_LOCATION("University");
    session.save(department);


    Employee EMP = new Employee();
    EMP.setENROLMENT_NO(2007255);
    EMP.setENROLMENT_NO(3794);
    EMP.setFIRSTNAME("FirstName");
    EMP.setLASTNAME("Gernaline");
    EMP.setBIRTH_DATE(new Date());
    EMP.setCELLPHONE("011899954");
    EMP.setDEP(department);

    department.getEMPLOYEE_LIST().add(EMP);

        session.save(EMP);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();

}
```

}

Even after adding the whole Set, i am getting Null Pointer Exception at this line : department.getEMPLOYEE_LIST().add(EMP);
Where am i getting wrong?

Comment: Has `EMPLOYEE_LIST` been initialized? Why the UPPERCASE for this variable?

Comment: @Reimeus So,`TATA CONSULTANCY SERVICES, (experts in that particular Banking domain) use uppercase. INTERESTING!!!

Comment: Well thanks for the answer. department.setEMPLOYEE_LIST(new HashSet<>()); // You can add this line
 department.getEMPLOYEE_LIST().add(EMP); that solved my problem. what else you can get from a well experienced person in this world?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialized `EMPLOYEE_LIST` in `department`.

```
 department.setEMPLOYEE_LIST(new HashSet<>()); // You can add this line
 department.getEMPLOYEE_LIST().add(EMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your department class, you have not initialized set and also you have not done it before persisting as well.

so either do `Set<Employee> EMPLOYEE_LIST = new HashSet<Employee>();`in department class.

or do like below before persisting department object

```
department.setEMPLOYEE_LIST(new HashSet<>());
department.getEMPLOYEE_LIST().add(EMP);
```

Comment: @KaribasappaGC, Why would you copy code from another answer to post as your own answer?
At least you could have done `department.setEMPLOYEE_LIST(new HashSet<Employee>());`

Comment: @TheKojuEffect :  i have not copied..i have expressed my view..where is Set<Employee> EMPLOYEE_LIST = new HashSet<Employee>(); in any answer..and second part i added it and its also there is someone else answer..but everybody in java creates hashset in the same way and adds element to collection using add  method..these are api in java..i have learned so much java from oracle, so i never copy from anyone , and that copy paste wont enhance our knowledge moreover .. if you think in that way i cant help you...